# Cant get xdebugger to connect (vagrant laravel phpstorm)

Tags: laravel, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a vagrant running serving to 
localhost:8931

When i use the phpstorm 'Validate Debugger Configuration' everything seems to be fine. [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG78e.png)

But when i connect to the site with breakpoints in the code, and breaking on first line of php script toggled on the connection request window doesn't show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first start listening for remote connections (Run | Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections). Also you need to have XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM somewhere in $_REQUEST. I use cookie for toggling the debugger (add [bookmarklets](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/) to your browser).

Also check if you have these settings in php.ini:

```
; disable profiler
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
; enable if ?XDEBUG_PROFILE is added to URL
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.default_enable = "Off"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```

Comment: I ended up using these settings 

xdebug.remote_enable=1

xdebug.remote_connect_back=1

xdebug.remote_port=9000

xdebug.remote_host=192.168.33.10

xdebug.ide_key=PHPSTORM

And placing them in the xdebug.ini extension